# PDF.js - “ReferenceError: TextLayerBuilder is not defined” when trying to add a Text layer

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations, pdf.js

When I tried [this](http://www.ryzhak.com/converting-pdf-file-to-html-canvas-with-text-selection-using-pdf-js/) example, the pdf is displayed but I don't have TextLayer that I could use for highlighting text and what not. I tried the proposed solutions in the comments of the example, but it still doesn't work for me? Any ideas on how I can fix that? If that's not possible can someone tell how to add a layer on top of a pdf that I can use to highlight/select text?

Thanks

Comment: PDF.js code is split into modules, so you cannot just access TextLayer from global scope. See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/pageviewer.js if you just want to see complete page rendered with text layer.